# Error: when render all value as json from Database in Grails 2.5.1

Tags: grails

**LoginController.groovy**

```
package nvts.sample

import grails.converters.*

class LoginController {

    static LoginService loginService

    def index() {
        render "Sample"
    }

    def getall() {
        def user = User.list()
        render user as JSON
    }
}
```

The first method called `index()` is rendering string value but `getall()` method not rendering JSON value.

Red error line in `def user = User.list()`

```
URI 
    /sample/login/index
Class
    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message
    No such property: User for class: nvts.sample.LoginController
```

`User` is my domain class which is created by reverse engineer:

**User.groovy**

```
package sample

class User {

    String emailAddress
    String userPasswd
    String payrollId
    String posLoginId
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String designation
    String dept
    String loginName
    String nric
    Date dateofbirth
    String phyAddr1
    String phyAddr2
    String phyAddr3
    String phyCity
    String phyState
    String phyCountryCode
    String phyPostalCode
    String postalAddr1
    String postalAddr2
    String postalAddr3
    String postalCity
    String postalState
    String postalCountryCode
    String postalPostalCode
    String telephone
    String handphone
    String altEmail
    String createdBy
    Date dateCreated
    String updatedBy
    Date dateUpdated
    String userMenu
    String emailAddress_1
    String altEmail_1
    String createdBy_1
    Date dateCreated_1
    Date dateUpdated_1
    String firstName_1
    String lastName_1
    String loginName_1
    String payrollId_1
    String phyAddr1_1
    String phyAddr2_1
    String phyAddr3_1
    String phyCity_1
    String phyCountryCode_1
    String phyPostalCode_1
    String phyState_1
    String posLoginId_1
    String postalAddr1_1
    String postalAddr2_1
    String postalAddr3_1
    String postalCity_1
    String postalCountryCode_1
    String postalPostalCode_1
    String postalState_1
    String updatedBy_1
    String userMenu_1
    String userPasswd_1

    static mapping = {
        id name: "emailAddress", generator: "assigned"
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        emailAddress maxSize: 45
        userPasswd maxSize: 45
        payrollId nullable: true, maxSize: 20
        posLoginId nullable: true, maxSize: 10
        firstName maxSize: 45
        lastName nullable: true, maxSize: 45
        designation nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        dept nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        loginName nullable: true, maxSize: 45
        nric nullable: true, maxSize: 10
        dateofbirth nullable: true
        phyAddr1 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        phyAddr2 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        phyAddr3 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        phyCity nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        phyState nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        phyCountryCode nullable: true, maxSize: 10
        phyPostalCode nullable: true, maxSize: 10
        postalAddr1 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        postalAddr2 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        postalAddr3 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        postalCity nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        postalState nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        postalCountryCode nullable: true, maxSize: 10
        postalPostalCode nullable: true, maxSize: 10
        telephone nullable: true, maxSize: 20
        handphone nullable: true, maxSize: 20
        altEmail nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        createdBy nullable: true, maxSize: 45
        dateCreated nullable: true
        updatedBy nullable: true, maxSize: 45
        dateUpdated nullable: true
        userMenu nullable: true
        emailAddress_1 maxSize: 45
        altEmail_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        createdBy_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 45
        dateCreated_1 nullable: true
        dateUpdated_1 nullable: true
        firstName_1 maxSize: 45
        lastName_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 45
        loginName_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 45
        payrollId_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 20
        phyAddr1_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        phyAddr2_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        phyAddr3_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        phyCity_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        phyCountryCode_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 10
        phyPostalCode_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 10
        phyState_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        posLoginId_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 10
        postalAddr1_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        postalAddr2_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        postalAddr3_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        postalCity_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        postalCountryCode_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 10
        postalPostalCode_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 10
        postalState_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        updatedBy_1 nullable: true, maxSize: 45
        userMenu_1 nullable: true
        userPasswd_1 maxSize: 45
    }
}
```

Comment: could you once try importing User class in controller. I guess controller is not able to see User as class

Comment: I have imported my self even same error came Mr. @user3919311

Comment: could you try once User.get or User.findBy as well. This error seems to be very weird.

Comment: I will try and let you know soon @Anshul

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing an import of the `User.groovy` class in your `LoginController.groovy` class?

```
import sample.User
```